# Instagram API deprication and switching to Graph APIs

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

We are currently using the [Instagram APIs](https://www.instagram.com/developer) to get the authentication token by asking users to login with instagram on our application. Once we get the authentication token we are using it to get the number of likes on a particular media using `/media/{media-id}/likes`

But as you can see facebook is deprecating these APIs and connecting instagram with Graph APIs. I have converted by instagram profile to business profile and have got the access to graph apis.

The question i have now, is will i be able to track the media likes using the graph APIs ?

Answer (score 0):

The below curl helps you to get the likes count on a media

```
curl -i -X GET \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/<instagram business account id>/media? 
   fields=id%2Cig_id%2Ccomments_count%2Clike_count&access_token=<access_token>"
```

Replace the place holders of access_token and instagram business account id with original values

Comment: please check my new question here and respond if you have any solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53078441/instagram-mention-api-not-able-to-retrieve-media-details-in-dev-mode